# keyboard interrupt routine visual studio C++ console app

Tags: keyboardinterrupt, visual-c++-2008

I am using VS 2022 Preview to write a C++ console application. I wish to detect a keyboard hit and have my interrupt handler function called. I want the key press detected quickly in case main is in a long loop and therefore not using kbhit().

I found signal() but the debugger stops when the Control-C is detected. Maybe it is a peculiarity of the IDE. Is there a function or system call that I should use?

Edit: I am vaguely aware of threads. Could I spawn a thread that just watches kbd and then have it raise(?) an interrupt when a key is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it by adding a thread. On the target I will have real interrupts to trigger my ISR but this is close enough for algorithm development. It seemed that terminating the thread was more trouble than it was worth so I rationalized that I am simulating an embedded system that does not need fancy shutdowns.

I decided to just accept one character at a time in the phony ISR then I can buffer them and wait and process the whole string when I see a CR, a simple minded command line processor.

```
// Scheduler.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <conio.h>

void phonyISR(int tbd)
{
    char c;
    while (1)
    {
        std::cout << "\nphonyISR() waiting for kbd input:";
        c = _getch();
        std::cout << "\nGot >" << c << "<";
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int tbd;
    std::thread t = std::thread(phonyISR, tbd);

    // Main thread doing its stuff
    int i = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        Sleep(2000);
        std::cout << "\nMain: " << i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: reopen the address question as I was writing the answer for you for 20 min and you just deleted it. Always wait at least one hour before deleting. It makes no sense to help people with youe low reputation because of this stupid behaviour.